# Why documents aren't added in order in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Code:**

```
CollectionReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection("users");
Map<String, dynamic> dummyData = {};

List elements = List.generate(5, (index) => index);
Future.forEach(elements, (element) async {
  dummyData["key"] = "$element";
  await reference.add(dummyData);
});
```

As you can see I am awaiting on every add. But the data I'm seeing on firebase console is in this order:

```
randomId:
  key: 3
randomId:
  key: 4
randomId:
  key: 1
randomId:
  key: 0
randomId:
  key: 2
```

However it should be:

```
randomId:
key: 4
randomId:
key: 3
randomId:
key: 2
randomId:
key: 1
randomId:
key: 0
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, I am newbie to both Flutter and Firebase.

---

**Edit:**

I am not fetching the data, rather writing it on the server. The data should have been written in the same order I am writing in code, isn't it?

Comment: Firebase stores data arbitrarily since it's noSql. if you want to get data in order you will have to sort by key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of documents that you see in the Firebase console is based on the unique document ID that it was given at the time the document was added.  Since you're using add(), a random document ID was given to it by the SDK.  Therefore, the documents will appear in random order in the console.  This is to be expected.  There is nothing wrong here.

When you go to query the documents, if you want them in another order, you will have to specify that in your query.  It sounds like you're able to use the `key` field for that. However, you should be storing a number instead of a string, so that the sort order makes sense if you want an ascending numerical sort.

Comment: Clear and precise. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code, usually documents are displayed in order of it's document key by default, while retrieving data if you want data in order of **key** defined by you then use **[OrderBy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?authuser=1#order_and_limit_data)** clause either in descending or ascending order.

Comment: Thanks but I am not asking about retrieving the data, I am only writing it on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase data is sorted alphabetically and all newly inserted data will be rearranged accordingly for indexation purposes. As such to get ordered data you will have to make use of firebase ordering functions like:

```
.orderBy()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I am not looking for fetching the data in a given order, I am writing the data on server.